# How Can I Grab Date Only from a Variable of Type DateTime?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

```
DataTable tempTable = new DataTable;
.
.
.
tempTable = getCustomerTable();
```

In this case, tempTable will have a table (named CustomerInvoice) which has
5 columns. The 3rd column is named DueDate. I print to a listview
as following:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < tempTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow row = tempTable.Rows[i];

                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(row["CuInvoiceID"].ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(row["CustomerQuoteID"].ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(row["DueDate"].ToString());

                lstvRecordsCInv.Items.Add(lvi);
            }

            tempTable.Clear();
```

This is how DueDate value looks like on UI:

[image]

I want it to look like this without time:

July 04, 2010
August 20, 2011

I prefer to solve this problem at application rather than db level.

NOTE: DueDate in database is of type datetime.

I'm coding in C# interacting with Sql-Server.

I hope my question is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
lvi.SubItems.Add(row["DueDate"].ToString());
```

You can do something like:

```
DateTime lDate = row["DueDate"] as DateTime;
lvi.SubItems.Add(lDate.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");
```

The values in the "MMMM dd, yyyy" string come from [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) (you can also use standard date formats from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx))

If you want to do any actual calculations on just the date you could use lDate.Date

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ToString method of DateTime to define the format.

```
row["DueDate"].ToString("dd MMM yyyy"); // 04 Jul 2010
```

Look up [DateTime.ToString(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) to see the various formats.

Comment: You need to cast the result of row["DueDate"] to an instance of DateTime before you can use that overload of ToString()...

Answer (score 0):

format it as it enters, so for your format ammend to the line below

```
lvi.SubItems.Add(row["DueDate"].ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the default DueDate.ToString(), pass a format string to "ToString", like this:

dateOnly.ToString("d")

"d" specifies to print the date only.

Comment: Or, to get your exact formatting requirements, use this format string:
"MMMM dd, yyyy"